# Stein manifolds coming from neighbourhood of critical fibers in elliptic fibrations

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact, Kähler surface (so $\dim X = 4$) and let  $f:X\to \mathbb{CP}^1$ be an elliptic fibration, in particular $f$ is holomorphic.

Suppose that $p\in \mathbb{CP}^1$ is a *singular* value of $f$ and consider a closed ball $D\subset \mathbb{CP}^1$ centered at $p$, we take $D$ small enough that $\partial D\cap CritValues(f) = \emptyset$ .

Then $f^{-1}(D)$ is a compact 4-manifold with boundary having a Kähler structure,

> Q1: Is $f^{-1}(D)$ a Stein domain?  Recall that a Stein manifold is a proper complex submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb C^n$ and a Stein domain is a region of $M$ cut out by $g\leq c$ where $g:M\to \mathbb{R}$ is a J-convex proper Morse function and $c$ is a regular value.

**My approach**: from the classification of complex surfaces we know that $X$, is projective, i.e.  embeds in  $\mathbb {CP}^n$ , hence, by intersectig $X$ with an affine chart of $\mathbb {CP}^n$ if we can find an open ball $B \subset \mathbb {CP}^1$ containing $D\subset B$, such that $f^{-1}(B)\subset \mathbb C^n$ is a properly embedded complex submanifold.
At this point I would take $M=f^{-1}(B)$ and as $J$-convex function $g:M\to \mathbb{R}$ $g(x) = |f(x)|^2$.

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f^{-1}(D) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$. Then
$$
f^{-1}(b) \subset \mathbb{C}^n
$$
is a holomorphic embedding. It induces a notrivial holomorphic morphism from a smooth Riemann surface to $\mathbb{C}^n$. But any holomorphic function on a compact Riemann surface is constant, a contradiction.

Comment: Your argument makes sense to me, but then what is the problem with my approach above?

Comment: I don't understand your argument.

Comment: @Sasha Just pointing out a typo: "any holomorphic function on a *compact* Riemann surface"

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: Ariyan, thanks, edited!